# Running Kubernetes on Mac

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am running Kubernetes on my local Mac. I used MiniKube for running the cluster. All works fine, but getting unauthorised error on accessing the API.

https:///v1/services

```
{
"kind": "Status",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {},
"status": "Failure",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"reason": "Unauthorized",
"code": 401
}
```

I just followed the steps from the below site to install minikube.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

Below page for creating services,

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/

Am i missing any other setting?

Clicking "Settings" in the Kubernetes also gives me the following error.

" Forbidden (403)
You do not have required permissions to access this page."

Thanks

Comment: The page you linked to is only about minikube installation, you may have done a few further steps before getting to API settings. After installing via minkube, do you remember which documentation page you followed that mentions opening your `https:///v1/services` ?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17404 - This is what I followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. You need to authenticate with the API either with SSL certificate or other means like ie. Baerer token (use user/pass) to acquire the token.